# Signature not showing as intended

Tags: html, outlook

I have created an HTML signature

```
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
#acc {
width:700px;
margin-top: 5px;
border-top: solid red 1px;
padding-top:5px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#last{
float:right;
margin-top: 1px;
}
#blast{
margin-left: 10px;
}
#second{

}
#main{
width:700px;
height:300px;
}
#logo{
z-index:50;
position:absolute;
top:50px;
}
#bg{
z-index:1;
}
#green{
color:green;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
#footer{
margin-top:10px;
width:700px;
font-size:12px;
color:gray;
}
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Untitled-1) -->
<div id="main">
<a href="http://romero.group"><img id="bg" src="https://i.gyazo.com/86c63547132c53e29202725bb83381a1.png" width="700" height="230" alt=""></a>



<div id="acc">
<img src="http://www.manorsidejoinery.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/CHAS-acreddited-contractor.jpg" width="220" height="140" alt="">
<img id="second" src="https://www.buildingcentre.co.uk/system/images/images/000/066/507/original/Worksafe-contractor-Log1.jpg?1455634903" width="220" height="140" alt="">
<img id="blast" src="https://i.gyazo.com/8b787ac125b5ebad1a75b620a86346df.png" width="110" height="140" alt="">
<img id="last" src="https://i.gyazo.com/c3d58119498dcc3223b1bf20070f6f4b.jpg" width="110" height="140" alt="">
</div>
<div id="footer">
<div id="green"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/cde8ee05016520b0c7a753954c6a887e.png">Please consider the environment before printing this email message.</div>
This E-mail and any attachments are intended only for the individual or company to which it is addressed and any may contain information which is privileged, confidential and prohibited from disclosure or unauthorized use under applicable law. If you have received this email by mistake please notify <a href="mailto:james@romerointeriors.co.uk" target="_top">james@romerointeriors.co.uk</a> immediately. 
</br></br>
Romero Interiors is a Limited company registered in England and Wales | Registration number: 06923001 | Registered office: Solar House, 282 Chase Road, London, N14 6NZ
</div>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

When I test it on my browser, it comes out as intended:

> [image]

It come out as intended on my email, and when I email it to my Hotmail it works just fine.

Unfortunately in outlook 2016 when the person receives an email the signature is messed up, and it looks like this:

> [image]

Anyone has any idea why it displays differently in outlook only? As you can see, the red border, and the text below it all jump out of the box, on top of that the last certification image isn't floating right as intended.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! This was generated by photoshop originally, as I saved the image for web.  This isn't the issue, the issue is the red border and the text below all go outside the div box.

Comment: For email templates it is recommended that you use tables instead of divs. I would recommend using email tools such as https://litmus.com/ which will allow you to test your email code for various email clients.

Comment: Hi Heady12 thank you for your reply! I have tried using tables, but I end up with white lines in between rows and columns when I do that. Like so for example: https://gyazo.com/8cb1c549f3be1be6759a1655a18cd0f3

Comment: Looks like you need to remove the cell padding from your table rows and cells

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, these types of strange issues are quite common with different webmail / email providers and embedded content. You should understand that even if you fix this issue with Outlook 2016 you could have problems with other services, or your fixes could even suddenly stop working in the future (if/when the service providers make changes in their code).

With that said, it seems there may be a bug with outlook 2016 where your margin declarations need to have a capital 'M' for them to work properly (see this for reference: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/tips_and_tricks_outlook.com).

Additionally, float width and position CSS styles applied to div's do not work in Outlook. You may want to try using tables instead.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I will test this right now! Still doesn't explain why content jumps out of the div?